# PHP Error after upgrading from version 2.5.3 to 2.11.7

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades, php-errors

I'm getting the following errors after upgrading from EE version 2.5.3 to 2.11.7.

Any ideas how to solve this one?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/expressionengine/public_html/index.php:54)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 213

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/expressionengine/public_html/index.php:54)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 213

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/expressionengine/public_html/index.php:54)
Filename: core/EE_Input.php
Line Number: 213

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/expressionengine/public_html/index.php:54)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 475
```

Comment: Your real error(s) will be just above this list - are you sure you didn't miss something off the top?

Comment: That's all that's displaying? (http://tomperkins.net/) I had to add some special code to index.php to get that to display, turning on debugging did nothing.

Comment: Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death/18208549#18208549

Comment: Hm, strange. Make sure you have nothing before the opening `<?php` tag in index.php. Then try disabling extensions in your config file to see if it's a third party incompatibility - `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';`

Comment: That's now loading the site James, any ideas how I go about identifying which is causing the problem?

Comment: Go into the control panel and disable all extensions one-by-one, enable again globally in config, then enable one-by-one until you find the culprit. Did you upgrade all your add-ons before doing the EE upgrade? If not, you should do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55538/discussion-between-tom-perkins-and-james-smith).

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like some file either has whitespace inserted ahead of its opening `<?php` tag, or you have a file that is using closing PHP tags `?>` and has whitespace after it. ExpressionEngine files do not use a closing PHP tag for this reason.

If it happened after an upgrade and that's the only change, there is a chance that a file got corrupted in deployment (FTP errors for example). You might try re-uploading the system files if you aren't able to spot the whitespace easily in user-modified-files.